# Laravel - PHP Fatal error when running php artisan serve with increased memory_limit

Tags: php, laravel, memory-limit

I'm encountering a PHP Fatal error in my Laravel project when running `php artisan serve`. The error message is as follows:

```
php artisan serve

   INFO  Server running on [http://127.0.0.1:8000].

   Press Ctrl+C to stop the server

   WARN  PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in C:\projects\laravel\storage\framework\views\3013c4ad2c85349d3078c69a5161cf9c.php on line 96.

   WARN  PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 888832 bytes) in C:\projects\laravel\vendor\spatie\ignition\src\ErrorPage\ErrorPageViewModel.php on line 104.

  2023-11-04 15:33:26 .............................................................................................. ~ 15s
  2023-11-04 15:33:26 ............................................................................................. ~ 133s
```

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name

----                 -------------         ------ ----

d-----         11/4/2023   2:50 PM                .git

d-----         11/4/2023   2:50 PM                .vite

d-----         11/4/2023   2:50 PM                app

d-----         11/4/2023   2:50 PM                bootstrap

d-----         11/4/2023   2:50 PM                config

d-----         11/4/2023   2:50 PM                database

d-----         11/4/2023   2:50 PM                node_modules

d-----         11/4/2023   2:50 PM                public

d-----         11/4/2023   2:50 PM                resources

d-----         11/4/2023   2:50 PM                routes

d-----         11/4/2023   2:50 PM                storage

d-----         11/4/2023   2:50 PM                tests

d-----         11/4/2023   2:52 PM                vendor

-a----         11/2/2023  12:25 PM            258 .editorconfig

-a----         11/4/2023   2:43 PM           1171 .env

-a----         11/2/2023  12:25 PM           1116 .env.example

-a----         11/2/2023  12:25 PM            186 .gitattributes

-a----         11/2/2023  12:25 PM            243 .gitignore

-a----         11/2/2023  12:25 PM           1686 artisan

-a----         11/2/2023   3:02 PM           1553 base.txt

-a----         11/4/2023   2:30 PM          58167 composer-setup.php

-a----         11/2/2023  12:25 PM           1882 composer.json

-a----         11/2/2023  12:25 PM         296306 composer.lock

-a----         11/2/2023  12:25 PM            113 db.sql

-a----         11/2/2023  12:25 PM          83555 package-lock.json

-a----         11/2/2023  12:25 PM            415 package.json

-a----         11/2/2023  12:25 PM           1084 phpunit.xml

-a----         11/2/2023  12:25 PM             80 postcss.config.js

-a----         11/2/2023   6:30 PM           4230 README.md

-a----         11/2/2023  12:25 PM            218 tailwind.config.js

-a----         11/2/2023  12:25 PM            263 vite.config.js

Here are some details about my environment:

- Laravel Installer: 5.1.3
- PHP Version: 8.2.12
- Operating System: Windows
- Database: MySQL

I've attempted to increase the `memory_limit` in my `php.ini` file from `256M` to `512M`, but I'm still encountering the same error when running `php artisan serve`.

I would appreciate any guidance or insights into resolving this issue. Thank you for your assistance!

**Additional Information:**

- Laravel Installer: 5.1.3
- PHP Version: 8.2.12
- Operating System: Windows
- Database: MySQL
- Memory limit in php.ini: `memory_limit = 512M`

Comment: How much Installed RAM is available on this server?  Rgt clk on window in lower left corner, System will display Installed RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Open the PHP `php.ini` file. On Windows, it can be found in the PHP installation folder, such as `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` if you are using XAMPP.

Locate the memory_limit directive and set a higher value, such as 256M, to allow PHP to use 256 megabytes of memory:

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

Save the `php.ini` file and restart the PHP server (or XAMPP if applicable). Run php artisan serve again, and the PHP Fatal error should be resolved. Adjust the memory_limit value as needed.

*Check the PHP settings after the restart using `phpinfo()` or `php -i`.*